# Разрешить вход в админку WordPress только с конкретного устройства

Tags: wordpress, логин

Здравствуйте. Можно ли разрешить вход в админку WordPress только с определенного планшета/ноутбука, и запретить вход с других устройств (даже если логин/пароль введены правильно)?
Ограничение по IP не подходит, так как он динамический.
Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Проверять по мак-адресу?

Comment: @gil9red Мак-адрес не уникален и его легко подделать. И достать его из браузера непросто.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, его еще узнать нужно... Ладно, а если завести свой сертификат и им подписывать запросы?

Comment: @gil9red тут вопрос - от кого защита? От человека, который должен работать только в офисе? Так он утащит сертификат на свой домашний компьютер. И как подписывать запросы? Это выливается в неслабый функционал расширения стандартного входа в WordPress. На коленке не сделать.

Comment: С динамическим IP тоже решается. Можно занести сегменты, а можно предварительно по ФТП менять на актуальный. Но можно ещё сделать http-авторизацию.

Answer (score 0):

Само по себе определение конкретного устройства проблематично. Можно воспользоваться двухфакторной аутентификацией. Вот неполный перечень плагинов, которые её поддерживают:

- [Duo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duo-wordpress/)
- [Google Authenticator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-authenticator/)
- [Rublon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rublon/)
- [WordFence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Но задача такая: нужно дать человеку возможность входить в админку и работать в ней только с моего устройства, которое всегда находится в офисе. Чтобы нельзя было войти в админку из другого места с другого устройства.